# Explanation of the transformation of a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have come across the differential equation $y''+ky=0$ which is solved by using the transform $y(x)=z[r(x)]$.

So the equation is transformed into $z''+z=0$.

Two partial solutions are:

$y_{1}=\cos \sqrt{kx}$

$y_{2}=\sin \sqrt{kx}$

So:

$y(x)=z[r(x)]=\cos r=\cos \sqrt{kt}$

$y(x)=z[r(x)]=\sin r=\sin \sqrt{kt}$

What I can't understand is how the $k$ disappeared. Shouldn't the equation transformed into $z''+kz=0$?